# Deploy mongo-express with cert (https) with docker-compose

Tags: mongodb, docker, nginx, https, docker-compose

Is there option to deploy the `mongo-express` service with domain CERT (using HTTPS) with docker compose? I have an existing web site with CERT (It uses HTTPS) and I want to integrate the `mongo-express` to it. So I want to deploy it as `https://my_host:8081`.

My current test `docker-compose.yml` file works perfectly but it uses the HTTP protocol (`http://localhost:8081`).

**My current test `docker-compose.yml` file:**

```
version: "3.8"

services:
  db:
    container_name: mongo-dev
    hostname: mongo-dev
    image: mongo:4.2
    environment:
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=admin
      - MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE=auth
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=pass
    networks:
      - mongo-compose-network
    ports:
      - '27017:27017'
    volumes:
      - ./data:/data/db

  mongo-express:
    container_name: mongo-express
    image: mongo-express:0.54.0
    depends_on:
      - db
    networks:
      - mongo-compose-network
    environment:
      - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_SERVER=mongo-dev
      - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINUSERNAME=admin
      - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINPASSWORD=pass
      - ME_CONFIG_BASICAUTH_USERNAME=admin
      - ME_CONFIG_BASICAUTH_PASSWORD=tribes
    ports:
      - '8081:8081'
    restart: on-failure

networks:
  mongo-compose-network:
    driver: bridge
```

I know that it can be done with `NgInx` but probably there is an embedded option for it. I have already read the documentation as well as the GitHub issues/pull-request but I didn't find any related topics. It is it not possible by default then I am open for a `NgInx` based solution.

Comment: have you tried putting an Nginx proxy to handle the TLS termination in front of the mongo-express container?

Comment: Nope! If you check my answer then you can see you can set the TLS with the `ME_CONFIG_SITE_SSL_ENABLED`, `ME_CONFIG_SITE_SSL_CRT_PATH` and `ME_CONFIG_SITE_SSL_KEY_PATH` environment variables. Current the `mongo-express` works as expected on `HTTPS` protocol.

Comment: IN your answer you've mentioned you don't have "admin features" so did it change? cause you now write that it "works as expected" in your comment

Comment: Yeah... The "admin features" doesn't work with the `1.0.0-alpha.4` or `latest` Docker image but it is a different story. I had focused to deploy the service on HTTPS protocol. But as I mentioned the issue has been reported to `mongo-express` team. But if you check the related bug report then you can find work-around for it but in that case you have to build an own Docker image. I wait the new Docker image version with the fix instead. :)

Comment: if the admin features are available in the HTTP configuration you could add an Nginx HTTPS reverse proxy to add that functionality this way, though I understand if you prefer to wait instead

Comment: Not really. The `Nginx` wouldn't solve this issue. The "admin features" problem is not related to HTTP or HTTPS protocols. It is a BUG so it doesn't work even if the `ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ENABLE_ADMIN` variable is set to `true`. It is described in the BUG tickets on GitHub.

Comment: I see, and do you know of a previous version where it worked just fine?

Comment: Yeah, the  "admin features" work as expected with the `0.54.0` version. This is the previous version of `latest` so this is the most up-to-date version where the "admin features" works. BUT with that version the TLS doesn't work. So have to choose between the "admin features" or TLS. Or, of course, you can choose the "admin features" and solve the TLS with the `Nginx`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have managed to solve my issue with the `1.0.0-alpha.4` Docker image version.

**The service in `docker-compose.yml`:**

```
  mongo-express:
    container_name: mongo-express
    hostname: mongo-express
    image: mongo-express:1.0.0-alpha.4
    depends_on:
      - mongo1
      - mongo2
    networks:
      - mongo_net
    volumes:
      - ./certs/domain.crt:/public.crt
      - ./certs/domain.key:/domain.key
    environment:
      - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_URL=mongodb://admin:admin_pwd@mongo1:27017,mongo2:27017/?replicaSet=my-replica-set
      - ME_CONFIG_BASICAUTH_USERNAME=admin
      - ME_CONFIG_BASICAUTH_PASSWORD=admin_pwd
      - ME_CONFIG_OPTIONS_EDITORTHEME=night
      - ME_CONFIG_SITE_SSL_ENABLED=true
      - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ENABLE_ADMIN=true
      - ME_CONFIG_SITE_SSL_CRT_PATH=/public.crt
      - ME_CONFIG_SITE_SSL_KEY_PATH=/domain.key
    ports:
      - '8081:8081'
    restart: on-failure
    deploy:
      mode: replicated
      replicas: 1
      placement:
        constraints: [ node.role == manager ]
    logging:
      driver: "fluentd"
      options:
        fluentd-address: ${SYSTEM_HOST}:24224
        tag: mongo-express
```

With the above service configuration the `mongo-express` will be running on `https://localhost:8081` site.

**NOTE:**

The admin features are not available in `1.0.0-alpha.4` or `latest` Docker image even if `ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ENABLE_ADMIN` parameter is set to `true`. The bug is known and it has been reported more times on GitHub. Eg.: https://github.com/mongo-express/mongo-express/issues/647. I am waiting for the fix...